.NET 8 EF Core is setting discriminator to the wrong value in the IdentityUserRole table
I've customized Identity and using code-first scaffolded the Identity tables in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. The problem I'm having is EF Core is putting in a value of IdentityUserRole<string> in the Discriminator column.
However, when I query the ApplicationUserRole table or use UserManager to get the user's roles, it is not returning any results because it's adding ApplicationUserRole to its SQL Server query. If I update all the values in the ApplicationUserRole Discriminator column, everything works fine, except I can't stop EF Core from adding IdentityUserRole<string> in the Discriminator column when I add a user to a role.
Any idea on how I've misconfigured Identity? I've done this plenty of times in .NET 6 and 7 with no issues.
ApplicationDbContext.cs:
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
    // setup identity schema
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationUser"); });
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationRole"); });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationClaim"); });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationUserLogin"); });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationUserToken"); });
    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationRoleClaim"); });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationUserRole"); x.HasKey(z => new {z.RoleId, z.UserId}); });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationUserClaim"); });        

Program.cs:
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        })
        .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

When a new role is added.
@p35='80831D3B-6B16-4738-B739-611366204346',
@p36='6d405f62-54e1-4bd1-84b7-ddd5e3403089'
@p37='IdentityUserRole<string>' 

INSERT INTO [ApplicationUserRole] ([RoleId], [UserId], [Discriminator])
VALUES (@p35, @p36, @p37);

When EF Core queries for a user role
SELECT TOP(1) [a].[RoleId], [a].[UserId], [a].[Discriminator]
FROM [ApplicationUserRole] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUserRole' 
    AND [a].[UserId] = @__userAdded_Id_0 
    AND [a].[RoleId] = @__role_Id_1


Replace builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationUserRole"); with builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(x => { x.ToTable("ApplicationUserRole");. If you mention in builder base class, EF Core automatically builds Type per Hirarchy between base class and descndant.

I got rid of all the ToTable code, deleted the database, recreated the database, ran a code first migration and the discriminator column is gone from all tables.   I think I pulled that code from a .NET 2 or 3 project so maybe .NET 8 doesn't like it.  Appreciate the help!
